# Node-Red Image on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I am performing object detection on an image from a camera and storing it in a directory with a fixed name. Every few seconds, the image is updated and stored with the same name in the directory.

I am running node-red on my Mac. I want to show this image on my npm dashboard and update it update it every time the source image is updated. Is there a way to do this?

I tried with the media node in the node-red dashboard but it doesn't update my image.
PLease help.

Comment: Use an UI Control to update the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in two parts:

1. Setting *httpStatic* in the *settings.js* file
2. Setting up the *template node* in node-red

**Setting httpStatic**

1. Go to the folder *~/.node-red* and open the *settings.js* file
2. In this file, uncomment the line starting with *httpStatic* and put in the path to the directory/ folder where the images are stored.The line of code will look like: `httpStatic: 'Path to your folder',`
3. Restart Node RED

This sets up the path you provided as the root directory for Node RED from which it'll start searching for your files

**Setting up template node in Node RED**

1. Bring in a template node and put in the following code:

   ```
   <body>
   <script>
   setInterval(function(){
       $("#myimg").attr("src", "path to your image w.r.t. httpStatic?"+new 
        Date().getTime());
        },7000);
   </script>
   <div style="height:500px;">
   <p align='center' id="box">
       <img src="path to your image w.r.t. httpStatic" id="myimg">
   </p>
   </div>
   </body>
   ```

The given above checks the directory in which you have the image(s) every 7 seconds and updates the images if the image changes.

**Note: Be sure to provide the path to the image with respect to the root directory set in httpStatic**

You can change the size of the division, alignment of the image and time interval for updation according to your need.